# How to replace models.ManyToManyField when the ForeignKey is now a GenericForeignKey

Tags: django, django-orm

Unsure of the right way to architect this situation -- would love some feedback.

I have two models, Story and User, that I want to be associated with a third model, Tag (that is, Users and Stories can be Tagged).

Originally I wrote this using standard foreign key and m2m relationships:

```
class Story(models.Model):
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(Place, through='StoryTagLink')

class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True, db_index=True)
    staff_created = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created_by = models.ForeignKey(User)
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True, editable=False)

class StoryTagLink(models.Model):
    story = models.ForeignKey(Story, db_index=True)
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, db_index=True)
```

Which naturally permitted me to easily do things like:

```
tags = story.tags.all()
```

or

```
{% if story.tags.count %}
```

The code around handling tags got sufficiently complicated that I decided it was better to use Generic Relations so I don't have the write same code twice, once for Story-Tag handling and again for User-Tag handling.  (I was literally starting to type the same code twice, just find-replacing Story for User.  And I figured it was better to use Generic Relationship than to try to hack together my own solution.)  Anyway, so now I have:

```
class Story(models.Model):
   tags = generic.GenericRelation(TagLink)

class Tag(models.Model):
    (same as before)

class TagLink(models.Model):
    tag = models.ForeignKey(Tag, db_index=True)  # <========== was this right???
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type',
                                               'object_id')
```

I made the `tag` field in the `TagLink` model a FK to the original `Tag` model to preserve the official list of site tags, because multiple objects can get the same tag, and I need each to have its own, unique ID and metadata.  The annoying side effect is that now when I do story.tags.all(), I get a list of `<TagLink: TagLink object>`s instead of the `Tag`s themselves as before.

When trying to research a better solution I notice that most other examples like mine seem to conflate my equivalent of the `Tag` and `TagLink` tables.  This doesn't seem like a workable solution in my case, but so many examples take that for granted that I wonder whether I'm missing something here, or if my case really is different from the others.

So:

1. What's the right way to handle the Tag and TagLink tables in my case -- am I right to keep them separate?
2. If so, is there a better way to construct queries to get all the tags for an object inside of my views and templates?
3. Given that my only reason for using Generic Relations was DRY (I don't have a case where I list all users and stories for a Tag -- I either list one or the other) and that there are only two kinds of objects that get tagged, would I be better off hacking together a solution that avoids Generic Relations and uses if-statements to create and save forms for both kinds of objects within the same function calls?  Given how much less flexible generic FKs are than regular FKs (I haven't even begun to address re-doing the admin, for ex), I'm beginning to regret going down this road at all...

Thanks for your time!!!